# Update from 16.04 LTS issues

Tags: 16.04, updates

I click Software & Updates, then the Updates tab.
I click the dropdown for "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" and try to pick "For any new version." The option does NOT change from "For long-term support versions".

I click Revert, nothing happens.
I click close and get a popup that says

> The information about available software is out-of-date. To install software and updates from newly added or changed sources, you have to reload the information about available software. You need a working internet connection to continue.

I have a working internet connection.
My two options are Reload and close. Close closes Software and Updates. Reload gives a popup that says

> You are not allowed to perform this action. You dont have the required privileges to perform this action.

I click details and it says

```
org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name' , {'name': ':1.109'}): org.debian.apt.update-cache
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **sudo** whenever it says you dont have required privilages..Open your terminal and type `sudo gnome-software` 
One more thing you can do is to use your terminal to download any packages you want, all you have to do is

```
sudo apt-get install <name of package/software>
```

To update and upgrade your ubuntu use

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: So did all that stuff which worked. I opened up Software Updater . It checked then the same "You are not allowed to perform this action" popup came up. I click close, then get another popup that says my software is up to date, but 18.04.1 LTS is available (you have 16.04). If I click "Upgrade..." it goes away and nothing happens. If I click "Settings..." it loops back into my original problem. If I click "OK" it just goes away

Comment: try using your terminal to upgrade if you want to, but first make backup of all your files  and type type 'do-release-upgrade' in your terminal..If you just want to install some packages use the 'sudo apt-get <package-name>

Comment: I did the release command and now it's doing its thing. If anything comes up, I'll let you know. Thank you for now

Comment: If its done, please mark it as solved. And yeah uh can ping me here ..lol :-D